# How to make a model that follows camera

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I want to add a 3D model that follows the camera of iOS device. My code so far but it's not enough because of no rotation. More to the point, I feel there is far easier solution like `SceneKit` inside `ARKit` so I would ask for your help:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    var timer = Timer()
    var pistolNode = SCNNode()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Create a new scene
        let pistol = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/pistol.dae")!
        pistolNode = pistol.rootNode.childNode(withName: "pistol", recursively: true)!
        pistolNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -0.3, -0.5)
        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pistolNode)

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.restartSession)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    @objc func restartSession()
    {
        pistolNode.position = SCNVector3Make((sceneView.pointOfView?.position.x)!, (sceneView.pointOfView?.position.y)! - 0.3, (sceneView.pointOfView?.position.z)! - 0.5)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var info: UILabel!
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A node will move along with the camera if it's added as a child node of the node containing the camera. You can get the node containing the camera with `sceneView.pointOfView?` and add `pistolNode` as one of its child nodes with its `addChildNode(child:)` method.

```
// Create a new scene
let pistol = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/pistol.dae")!
pistolNode = pistol.rootNode.childNode(withName: "pistol", recursively: true)!
pistolNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -0.3, -0.5)
// let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(pistolNode)

// Set the scene to the view
sceneView.scene = pistol
```